# How can I store a date in a MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to store a date value in a MySQL database.

I have one PHP page called `A.php` that has 3 inputs: `d`, `m`, `y`, where `d = (1 ... 31)`, `m =(1 ... 12)` and `y = (1970 to 2009)`.

Now in `b.php` I collect this values and I need to store in my db.

My DB has a field called `dob` which is of date type.

How can I construct a variable of type date from `d`, `m`, `y` and store it in the DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mysql date fields take the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' so store it as such, but pass it in as a string from PHP, including the dashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass it a string:

```
$sql = 'insert into tbl (dob) values 
        (\'' . $month . '/' . $day . '/' . $year . '\')';
```

MySQL will do the correct conversion for you, so you don't even have to worry about it.

Make sure that you've done [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://us.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent SQL injection on all of your variables.

Comment: How does MySQL know if it's in the format mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @andho: It's wicked smart. That, and it takes `mm/dd/yyyy`, not `dd/mm/yyyy` as a format.

Answer (score 1):

To construct a variable of type date, use the mktime() function:

```
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```

To store your $date in your database, convert the date to a string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (dob) VALUES ('" . date('Y-m-d', $date) . "')";
```

Alternatively, using mySQLi:

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (dob) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(?))');
$query->bind_param('i', $date);
$query->Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best to just store it as a UNIX timestamp in the db since it's crossplatform using

```
mktime()
```

Then, when you retrieve it from the db, use

```
date()
```

to convert it to whatever format you want (e.g. October 31, 2009; 10/31/2009; etc)

Answer (score 1):

too long. simply do:

```
$dt = sprintf("%'04s-%'02s-%'02s",$y,$m,$d);
mysql_query("insert into mytable (dob) values ('$dt')");
```